# multiple file download control with angular 6

Tags: angular

Hi I am in situation wherein I need to develop multiple file download controls in the form and this is angular 6 application.

file 1 donwload | pause  | delete
file 2 download | resume | delete
.......
and there is down the line i have button called download all.
**download all.**

Now the requirement is that for every 20 seconds it should give me response that how many progress has been done in downloading file and it update the progress bar, also I can pause and resume where I left last time.

How can I achieve this using observables?

Comment: what u have tried before..? put some code here we can't give you full solution for that you need to give some effort

Comment: I need to know what angular 6 capabilities are in terms to achieve this ?

Comment: have u seen this ..? [click here](https://www.truecodex.com/course/angular-6/file-upload-in-angular-6-7-with-progress-bar-using-web-api)